# How to create a link from node view and pass information to a webform

Tags: 8, webforms

In Drupal 8, I have a webform field attached to a node with the *Link to form* formatter enabled.

Can I add the ID of that node in the *Link custom attributes (YAML)* textarea to display a block view of some node fields?

My goal is to be able to use a contextual filter on the block view to display the node information like title and some other fields around the form

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: What's your end goal? I'm not quite following.

Comment: I have a just my question see above

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `webform link` field can be used to accomplish this as the purpose of `Link custom attributes (YAML)` is for HTML TAG attributes like

```
target: _blank
```

**You can use** [field_token_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_token_value) to create a field on the node that has tokens as input. Install and enable the module and then add a token field.

[image]

The value of this field would be an HTML link with query parameters added (`nodetitle` in this example) you can browser for all available tokens under field value.

[image]

Then on the webform side you have to enable query parameter to populate fields by going to the `settings of the webform > form > form behaviours > prepopulate > Allow all elements to be populated using query string parameters.`

[image]

And then on the field to display the query parameter include the appropriate token.  Here adding the `nodetitle` to the subject field default value.

[image]

For token field to be populated a node needs to be saved.